# Android, ListView, RadioButton

Tags: android-sdk, android

Можно ли в `ListView`, выбор элемента сделать, при помощи `RadioButton`, чтобы при этом выбирался только ОДИН элемент? Если да, то каким способом (скажите название метода, слушателя или еще что-то)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду, что вам надо при нажатии на элемент ставить галочку на нём и убирать её на других то вам надо:

1. Завести список **boolean** значений в классе адаптера.
2. При нажатии на к-л элемент всем элементам списка присвоить **false**, а нажатому true. После вызвать `notifyDataSetChanged()` метод адаптера.
3. В `getView()` методе адаптера проставлять галочку по проверке на **true**/**false** из этого списка по позиции элемента.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого нужно поместить RadioButton'ы в ListView. Подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347661/android-radio-button-in-custom-list-view) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250599/android-listview-with-radiobutton-in-singlechoice-mode-and-a-custom-row-layout). А, затем объединить их в одну RadioGroup.

Comment: А можно как-то без RadioButton? Просто все элементы списка загружаются из массива, а массив - из базы данных.